# retrieve all the elements of a column in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I explain my problem i try to recover all the content of a column from a text file in a list.

My text file looks like :

```
o_anl;Antoine;Legrand
o_lof;Loic;Formont
_boga;Bruno;Gauchet
o_geb;Guillaume;Babik
_dagu;Damien;Guermonprez
o_vata;Valérie ;Taillardat
maga;Marie;GALANO
```

I want to get all the data from the first column and put it in one list like this

```
[o_anl ; o_lof ; _boga ; o_geb]
```

I try :

```
id = row[1]
id = []
id.append(row[1])
print(id)
```

this code returns that to me :

```
['stra']
['thro']
['thro']
['thro']
['luhu']
['sapa']
['zitu'`]
```

And i want somethings like :

```
['stra' ; 'thro' ; 'luhu']
```

In a single list

i show you the rest of my code :

```
log = open("log.txt","r") 
for r in range(6, rows):
req = "SELECT * FROM users where last_name='"+feuille_1.cell_value(rowx=r, colx=4)+"' and first_name='"+feuille_1.cell_value(rowx=r, colx=5)+"'"
c.execute(req)
for row in c.fetchall():
          feuille_1.cell_value(rowx=r, colx=4)+" "+feuille_1.cell_value(rowx=r, colx=5)+" "+row[1]+" "+row[5]+" "+row[6]
```

It's the same problem now i want to recover all data from "row[1]" in a single list

Answer (score 2):

Try using the below code for reading the txt and splitting, remember to change `yourtextfile.txt` to the actual text file's name:

```
with open('yourtextfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    print([i.split(';')[0] for i in f])
```

Comment: It works thank you but can you help me with the rest of the code i just posted

Comment: @samuelL-M It's going to another topic now, i would suggest you to accept my answer and upvote if you hadn't, then go ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list containing each line of the file, you can use list comprehension.

```py
output = [x.split(';')[0] for x in data]
```

This will return a list of the first element on each line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file = open(<filename.txt>,'r').readlines()
output = [line[0] for line in file]
print(output)
```

Comment: When i try your code that returns me  :                                                                         
 ['a', 'o', 'o', '_', 'o', '_', 'o', 'm', 'o', 'o', 'o']

Comment: you can use `line.split(';')[0]` instead

Comment: additionally you can use csv module, file = `csv.reader(open(<fn>,'r'), delimiter=';')`